# Android - 'JDI thread evaluations' has encountered a problem

Tags: java, android

I am having errors with this code:

```
xmldata = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.map1);
for(int y = 0; y < 15; y++){
    st = new StringTokenizer(xmldata[y], ", "); // error here <<<
    // some other stuff
}
```

When I use the debugger on `xmldata`, I get this error on Eclipse:

```
'JDI thread evaluations' has encountered a problem.  
Exception processing async thread queue.
```

Details:

```
Exception processing async thread queue 
    Exception processing async thread queue 
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

The xml file itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="map1X">13</integer>
    <integer name="map1Y">7</integer>
    <string-array name="map1">
        <item>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</item>
        <item>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</item>
        <item>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2</item>
        <item>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2</item>
        <item>0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2</item>
        <item>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</item>
        <item>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</item>    
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Expressions View (if you Eclipse IDE, or any other Watch) to get the state of this/any variable, when this error happens. For some, unknown to me reason, Eclipse shows this errors sometimes when trying to show the variable using cursor...

Comment: Well it turns out that my problem was unrelated to the error and I fixed it. I guess it just so happens that Eclipse has trouble with showing me the contents of variable that is based on an xml file.. Anyway, thanks for the tip.